# Sending UDP packet through router and then broadcasting

Tags: udp

We have a network device on a network (10.0.0.90) which generates a UDP ASCII stream.  We need to send this to 8 machines (10.101.1.1 & 10.101.1.2 and 10.101.3.1 - 10.101.3.6)

We need to keep these two networks separated for everything other than this udp stream.

We have tried to do this fire walling via a router (Draytek Vigor 2830) however we are struggling.  At present the way we achieve this is to have the 10.0.0.90 machine generate and send all 8 packets and send them on 8 different ports to the router which then forwards them on.  This is killing the 10.0.0.90 machine which has other critical tasks to perform.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to achieve this.  Ideally this would be by using hardware rather than software solutions as it needs to just sit there for several years and just do its thing.

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question, you want the 10.0.0.90 to broadcast rather than use 8 ports?

Comment: Yeah creating the packet and sending it 8 times along with the other work this is doing is killing this machine so I need to do the message once. I was then hoping the router would help take the load of splitting it or broadcasting it

Comment: Can you use IP multicast?

Comment: Apparently I can't use igmp on the 10.101.x.x side but I believe there is a way to multicast without this I just don't know how.   Would this still work through the router.  I originally was doing this from the wan to the lan.  Now it seems I can do vlans so was going between two lan ports

Comment: IP multicast works through a router, I'm not sure what IGMP not working on one side means. IGMP snooping is available on the Draytek Vigor 2830.